# Copying dlls to a subdirectory msbuild

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am trying to build a project where I want dlls to be placed into a separate bin folder. I tried using Deploy Include but it didnt' help. Do you what is the correct way to do it ?

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Deploy Include="$(Outdir)$(TargetFileName)" />
    <Deploy Include="$(Outdir)$(TargetName).pdb" />
    <Deploy Include="$(Outdir)">
      <FileMatch>*.dll *.pdb</FileMatch>
      <Subdir>bin</Subdir>
    </Deploy>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You want to copy *.dll from $(OutDir) to some bin folder? Is that right?

Comment: yes you are correct..

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate item groups, one for exe the other for dlls

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Deploy Include="$(Outdir)$(TargetFileName)" />
  <Deploy Include="$(Outdir)$(TargetName).pdb" />
  <DeployBin Include="$(Outdir)*.dll" />
  <DeployBin Include="$(Outdir)*.pdb" Exclude="$(Outdir)$(TargetName).pdb" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The you can copy the files like this:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(Deploy)"
      DestinationFiles="$(MyDeployFolder)" />
<Copy SourceFiles="@(DeployBin)"
      DestinationFiles="$(MyDeployFolder)\bin" />
```